# CLT can be used for weighted sum of different Bernoulli variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose $$
z_i \sim Bernoulli (p_i)
$$

Can we use CLT for the following weighted sum?

$$
S = \sum_i w_i z_i 
$$

i.e. can $S$ be approximated with a normal distribution? If yes, with which theorem? (I suppose the classical CLT holds only for average of iid variables)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either the [Lyapunov CLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT) or the [Lindeberg CLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition) will be what you seek.

In each case let $X_i\,=\,w_i\,z_i$ and apply the theorems as given there to the $X_i$.

In a great many cases of the kind you suggest (and likely all that you care about), checking Lyapunov's condition should be sufficient.

However, unless you have some weird edge case, I think Lindeberg's should work in all cases of the kind you need.