# Can I usefully apply the Lyapunov CLT condition to a finite sum of Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: central-limit-theorem, bernoulli-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

I'd like to get a CLT-like approximate distribution (mostly tail behavior) of the sum $X$ of $n$ independent Bernoulli random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$, with proportions $p_1, \dots, p_n$.

The [Lyapunov CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT) seems like it could help (as mentioned in [CLT can be used for weighted sum of different Bernoulli variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89254/clt-can-be-used-for-weighted-sum-of-different-bernoulli-variables)).

But it's an asymptotic result on sequences of random variables. I have not become very familiar with this condition, but it seems like I could artificially construct $X_{n+1}, \dots$ such that the condition always holds? I'm not entirely sure on this point.

Is there some way to apply it more meaningfully?

If $p_1 = 0.5$ and $p_2, \dots, p_n$ are 0 (or extremely close to zero, like $1/2^{\max(100, n)}$), then clearly I should not be using a normal approximation for the distribution of $X =\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. My case is not so extreme, but there are some $p_i$ very close to 0/1.

Is there some common rule of thumb to use here? I suppose I could compute the Lyapunov CLT term for $\delta=1$ and compare this to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ (when sequence is iid Bernoulli($p$) the term seems to decrease as $\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $c$ is a function on $p$). The following is this Lyapunov CLT term -- if it approaches $0$ as $n \to \infty$ then the Lyapunov CLT condition is satisfied.
$$\frac{1}{s_n^3}\sum_{i=1}^n E \left[ |X_i - E[X_i]|^3 \right]$$

Alternate idea is to use a Chernoff bound.

Comment: If $p_2,...,p_n$ are very small, a Poisson approximation would be more useful than a Gaussian. You could then do a direct convolution with the first variable to get a good approximation to the combined distribution. If you have some very large $p$'s and some very small $p$'s you could do those as a shifted-Skellam. The general case of approximating a sum of independent Bernoullis with varying $p$ is the [Poisson-binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson-binomial_distribution) ... about which there are a number of questions already on site.

Comment: Sorry, the link should go here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution